# Difference between MySQL release versions

Tags: mysql

What is the difference between mysql-5.5.8.zip and mysql-5.5.8-win32.zip in the http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ download page. I have a Win 2K environment, what binary should I use and why does it have a huge size difference between the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smaller package does not contain test suite and embedded server.

Anyway, I suggest you use the MSI installer instead - installation and configuration are way more straightforward.

Comment: did you mean "smaller package"

Comment: I am on a slower connection, hence would just need the server piece alone without any other dependencies

Comment: Then I think you'll be fine with mysql-5.5.8.zip